# Do convergent power series form a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra

In my linear algebra class, I was wondering if convergent power series form a vector space?

Comment: Do they satisfy the vector space axioms with the usual operations? And, by power series do you mean series $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n x^n$ that converge on some open neighborhood of $0$?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Another point to ponder is whether or not it’s a complete vector space in some sense.

Comment: I think this is a good question.  Keep on wondering about things!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, indeed! :) To be a bit more precise, of course, you might want to specify the "center point" of the power series, for example $0$, so that you're looking at $\sum_{n\ge 0} c_n\,x^n$, with $\limsup_n |c_n|^{1/n}<+\infty$